Creating a table in Google Docs via API; if it splits across pages then add headers using Java
I am dynamically generating a table in Google Docs using the Google Docs API, with the table data provided in JSON format from an API. I need to check if the table rows across multiple pages. If it does, I want to split the table into separate tables and add a header row to the new table at the start of the next page. I have text paragraph also on the pages. How can I implement this using Java in a Spring Boot application?
I tried for checking page brakes & page number changes as well but as table has dynamic value can not calculate for the indexes.

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

I have created a table using JSON data received from an API response. This table spans multiple pages when generating a report. I need to add a header to the table on each new page. Currently, Google Docs treats all the data as a single continuous table and automatically divides it across pages based on the index. Since the data is dynamic, I cannot use a fixed index to determine page breaks. Is it possible to add a table header whenever the table splits across pages using Java Spring Boot?
